# How can I echo a COUNT query with group function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to mySQL and as such am just looking for a very simple COUNT query which I haven't found explained online with any real clarity.

What I'm looking to do is

COUNT the number of school children group by their age

Comment: Can you post your table and your query??

Comment: `Select count(*) from table_name group by age`

Comment: `select age,count(*) from table_name group by age` (you were missing age in the select)

Comment: this is the query ("SELECT gendar, count(teachercode) from teacher group by gendar") and there is two fields of table. they are not eco properly

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY age;
```

This query will print out the age and the number of children for each age.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you can do this sql command:
"select count(nr_children) from children group by age";

or in php:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "select * from children group by age";
$children = $conn->query($sql);
$nr_child = mysqli_num_rows($children);
echo $nr_child;
```

Comment: <body>
<?php
include("connection.php");
?>
<table border="1px">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
</tr>
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT gendar, count(teachercode) from teacher group by gendar") or die (mysql_error());
?>
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
 <tr>
    <td>
<a href="student.php?sr=<?php echo $row['sr'];?>">
<?php echo $row['gendar']?></a> </td><td> <?php echo $row['count( teachercode )']?></td>
</tr>
this is my code but not working properly <?php }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>